# Wordpress Rest API V2 - How to filter comments?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to fetch all pending comments using Wordpress Rest API v2 using URL like http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?filter[status]=hold but it returns all comments

I have tried some other variation like below but none is working

http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?status=hold

What should be the correct way to get Pending comments using Wordpress Rest API v2?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering with ?status=hold works but only if your API request is authenticated

Answer (score -2):

/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/?post=15418 this is the correct way to filter your comments.Pass your post id to get filtered results

Comment: OP asked to "fetch all pending", which your answer completely misses.

Comment: Any solution for this situation?